# Insert shapes (graphics) from .tex files to a mainfile.tex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, includegraphics

I use Texstudio and MikTex 2.9
I want to insert shapes which drawled using `tikz` package in `Fig#.tex` files to a `main.tex` file. like this:

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{figs/Fig1.tex}
            \label{fig1}
        \end{figure}
```

This  work just fine in overleaf, but i get this error in TeXstudio

`Unknown graphics extension: .tex. \includegraphics[scale=1]{figs/Fig1.tex}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! With `includegraphics` you can import only graphics files which have extensions `pdf`, png`, jpeg` but not `.tex` files. They can be imported in main `tex` files by `\input` or `\include` commands.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much